# change domain internet explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10

When I try to login to our SharePoint site the authentication popup forces me to use the domain I'm currently using on my local computer. The SharePoint site does not have the same domain.

I'm running IE10 on Windows 7. How do I change the domain!?

I have tried the option "use another account" and enter in the field UserName: DOMAIN/username however it does not work. I also tried:

DOMAIN//username
domain//username
domain/username

I also unchecked the option 'Enable Integrated Windows Authentication ' in the 'Advanced' tab of Internet Security options.

I have access using mozilla and chrome;however I need to use only IE to enter to SharePoint.

Nothing has worked.

Comment: Did you also try DOMAIN\username? It looks like you only got wrong the slash.

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that detail. I can access now.